# Flutter don't show the image on the virtual device

Tags: image, flutter

I'm trying to execute an flutter application, but the image do not appears on the virtual device. After executing the program, it disappears (image), and only appears by deploying it again. What should i do? I'm a newbie programmer. Thanks a lot.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  height: 300,
  child: transacao.isEmpty
      ? Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("There's nothing to see here... strange...",
                style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme.title),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Image.asset(
                'others/images/koala.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for a while, if the image is big Flutter can take some time to show it.

If you want to load an image in memory and then show it, so it won't take a long time after you navigate to a new screen, call [`precacheImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html).